# how to use INNSER JOIN with BETWEEN in php

Tags: php

```
  $sql =  "SELECT * FROM crm_vendas WHERE venda_id BETWEEN '$value1' and '$value2'";
```

I created this item to use in the limited tables a search between the value 1 and 2, but it is necessary to use a connection of two tables, so I used:

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM crm_vendas INNER JOIN crm_vendas_detail ON crm_vendas.venda_id = crm_vendas_detail.venda_id";
```

but I can't use between to filter / narrow the search

is there any way to join the between and the inner join?

Comment: I just add an example to use between operator with sql like,,
SELECT 'Your Columns' FROM crm_vendas cv INNER JOIN crm_vendas_detail cvd ON cv.venda_id BETWEEN 1 and 20

Comment: Normally between use specific conditions like you compare date , given ids and other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question here is what is the relationship between the 2 tables:

- if there is at least one (or more) record in the crm_vendas_detail table for every crm_vendas record, then you can use the inner join as it is and add the condition to the end:

  ```
  $sql =  "SELECT * FROM crm_vendas INNER JOIN crm_vendas_detail ON crm_vendas.venda_id = crm_vendas_detail.venda_id WHERE crm_vendas.venda_id BETWEEN '$value1' and '$value2'";
  ```
- if a record from the crm_vendas table might not exist in the crm_vendas_detail table you will need to use left join:

  ```
  $sql =  "SELECT * FROM crm_vendas LEFT JOIN crm_vendas_detail ON crm_vendas.venda_id = crm_vendas_detail.venda_id WHERE crm_vendas.venda_id BETWEEN '$value1' and '$value2'";
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have venda_id defined on the two tables you have to specify the column by using table.column.

```
$sql="
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     crm_vendas 
INNER JOIN crm_vendas_detail ON crm_vendas.venda_id = crm_vendas_detail.venda_id"

WHERE 
     crm_vendas.venda_id BETWEEN '$value1' and '$value2'";
;
```